# How to get parameter from url in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm very new to react and am having trouble accessing the parameter from URL. I've looked for many solutions but I kept getting the same error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined". How can I access the param from url in reactjs component?

***In App.js***

```
render() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ResetPassword path="/reset-password/:token" />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

***In ResetPassword.js***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ResetPassword extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { token } = this.props.match.params.token;
    console.log(token);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="resetPassword">
        <div className="change__container">
          <form>
            <h1 id="changePassword__message"></h1>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="password"
              className="change__textInput"
              required
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="passwordTwo"
              placeholder="confirm password"
              className="change__textInput"
              required
            />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="change__btnInput btn" required />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

***Error***
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: That means you are not properly sending the params to the ResetPassword component, so when the component mounts there is no params. Check how you are setting the :token as the error is coming from there

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use react-router, you may try this:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router";
const { token } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add component as prop to access **match**

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

<Route
 path="/reset-password/:token"
 component={ResetPassword}
/>
```

or if you want pass custom props you can use render prop:

```
<Route
 path="/reset-password/:token"
 render={(props) => <ResetPassword {...props} myProp={"foo"} />}
/>
```

And for reading token you can do one of these ways:

```
const { token } = this.props.match.params;
const token = this.props.match.params.token;
```